# "Object doesn't support property or method 'push'"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to add new value into existing JSON object in AngularJS but I'm getting this error message:

```
"Object doesn't support property or method 'push'"
```

Here is my code:

```
$scope.addStatus = function (text) {          
          $scope.application.push({ 'status': text }); //I have tried 'put' but getting the error
      };

 $scope.create = function( application ){
        $scope.addStatus('Under review');
 }
```

here is my application json looks like:

```
{"type":"Not completed","source":"mail","number":"123-23-4231","amount":"234.44","name":"John ","id":"123","by_phone":true}
```

I want to append/add status to the above json and something looks like after adding the **status** property:

```
{"type":"Not completed","source":"mail","number":"123-23-4231","amount":"234.44","name":"John ","id":"123","by_phone":true, "status": "under review"}
```

Comment: Where is $scope.application defined?  If its not an array, then your code will fail.

Comment: @psl: how come you tag this is as duplicate? care to explain?

Comment: Because if you read the answer you will know. It is just worded differently. You should atleast put some effort to find out what the error message means, to start with (rather than pasting the error from the console in the question)... I am sorry i don't think there is no way it is not a duplicate. Hope this explains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.push()` is a method of an JS Array.

But application is just an object *(not an Array)*. Here we  can just use:

```
// instead of this
// $scope.application.push({ 'status': text });
// use this
$scope.application.status = text;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is only for arrays. Add the property in one of the following manners:

```
$scope.application['status'] = text;
```

Or:

```
$scope.application.status = text;
```